# Is this ER diagram correct for my brief?

Tags: database

I have the *very* simple brief of:

3 Entities: **Book**, **Author** & **Reviewer** with the relationships of **Writes** & **Reviews**

Occurrence Multiplicity:

- An author writes 1 or many Books
- Each book is written by between 1 & 5 Authors
- A book must be reviewed by at least 2 but no more than 6 reviewers
- A reviewer reviews between 1 and many books

My question is ***does this diagram look correct? Am I doing something horribly wrong?***

[image: My ER Diagram]

Comment: This very much looks like Class diagram than ER diagram :-) ER diagram has attributes as leaves in oval ;-)

Comment: That's probably very true, however my class requires me to submit like this :\

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about reviewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine except for the foreign keys (`authorId` and `reviewerId`) in your `Book` entity. You want to remove those, because all that data is provided by your association tables.

Also, you have the following rule:

> A reviewer reviews between 1 and many books

Your association on that end however specifies `0..*`, so that should probably be `1..*`.

Comment: Whoops! Thanks for spotting that one!

Answer (score 0):

The join tables: Writes and Reviews are all good. but, it's useless of FK: `authorId` and `reviewerId`!
The forreign key can only support many-to-one relationship. for your `book<->author` and `book <-> reviewer` are typical `many-to-many` relationship, so it's clear to use association (join) table.